# What's the area of the shaded regions in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In triangle ABC, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are areas of the shaded regions. If $S_1 \cdot{S}_2=16 cm^4$, calculate $MN$.

[image]

My progress:

$\frac{AM.DM}{2}.\frac{CN.FN}{2}=16 \implies AM.DM.CN.FN=64\\
\frac{S1}{S2} = \frac{AM.MD}{CN.FN}\\
\frac{S1}{\frac{MI.DM}{2}}=\frac{AM}{MI}\implies S1 = \frac{AM.DM}{2}\\
\frac{S2}{\frac{NI.FN}{2}}=\frac{CN}{NI}\implies S2 = \frac{CN.FN}{2}$

.....????

Comment: Is BI altitude ?

Comment: If you don't know that BI is altitude, provided data is not enough.

Comment: In your solution transition $\frac{AM}{MI}=\frac{AM}{2DM}$ is not correct. $MN=MI+IN=$ $\frac{DM^2}{AM}+\frac{FN^2}{CN}=$ $\frac{4S_1^2}{AM^3}+\frac{FN^3}{2S_2}=$ $\frac{4S_1^2}{AM^3}+\frac{AM^3 S_2^2}{2S_1^3}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu My failure. BI is height... I corrected the figure

Comment: I think you must mean $S_1\cdot S_2=16\text{cm}^4$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  "$(\frac{AM}{MI}=\frac{AM}{2DM})$ isnnot corret"....But I used the proportion between areas of triangles with the same height. Where is the error???

Comment: @TonyK thanks for alert..adjusted

Comment: If $\frac{AM}{MI}=\frac{AM}{2DM}$, then $MI=2DM$. But this is not true in general, is it?

Comment: @TonyK   I already saw where the error is..thankful

Comment: Question alternatives: $a)4,b) 4\sqrt2, c)\sqrt8, d) 4\sqrt3, e)8$

Comment: But now $\frac{AM}{MI}=\frac{AM\cdot DM}{2}\implies $MI\cdot DM=2$, which is also not true in general. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: By the way, given those alternatives, it's easy to pick the right one $-$ just draw a symmetrical figure. But that doesn't answer the question of why $MN$ is uniquely determined whatever the ratio of $S_1$ to $S_2$.

Comment: @TonyK The math notation was wrong..already corrected it..

Comment: Here's a Desmos of the thing: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/02wfdrik1z You can move the point $B$ and search for a suitable spot.

Comment: @ploosu2 I've checked with your Desmos plot, to make sure, answer $4\sqrt{2}$ is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\angle A=\angle IDM = \angle DIB = \angle IBF = \angle FIN = \angle CFN$$

$$\frac{DM}{AM}=\frac{IM}{DM}=\frac{FI}{BF}=\frac{FN}{IN}=\frac{CN}{FN}=x$$

$$DM=x AM, IM=x DM = x^2 AM,$$
$$BF=ID=\sqrt{IM^2+DM^2}=x AM \sqrt{1+x^2}, FI=x BF=x^2 AM \sqrt{1+x^2}$$
$$FI^2=IN^2+FN^2=IN^2+(x IN)^2=(1+x^2) IN^2 \Rightarrow IN=\frac{FI}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=x^2 AM$$
$$FN=x IN=x^3 AM, CN=x FN=x^4 AM$$

$$S_1=AM\cdot DM / 2 = x AM^2 / 2, S_2=FN\cdot CN / 2= x^7 AM^2 /2$$
$$S_1 S_2 = x^8 AM^4 / 4 \Rightarrow x^2 AM = \sqrt[4]{4S_1 S_2}$$
$$MN=IM+IN=2x^2 AM=\sqrt[4]{64 S_1 S_2}=4\sqrt{2} \rm{\ cm}$$

Answer (score 3):

Making a few observations does reduce the work considerably. Say $DM = x, FN = y$

[image]

First, observe that $~\displaystyle \frac{x}{AM} = \frac{CN}{y} \implies AM \cdot CN = xy$

$s_1 \cdot s_2 = \frac 12 AM \cdot x \cdot \frac 12 CN \cdot y \implies xy = 2 \sqrt{s_1 s_2} = 8$

Next observation: Given $BDIF$ is a rectangle, diagonals $BI$ and $FD$ are equal and $O$ is the midpoint of both diagonals. We also have, $DM \parallel OI \parallel FN$

That leads to $~OI = \dfrac{x+y}{2} \implies FD = BI = x + y$

Finally using Pythagoras, $MN^2 = (x+y)^2 - (y-x)^2 = 4xy = 32~$ and $~MN = 4 \sqrt2$.

Comment: Excellent ..thanks